# Deserialize property to different class based on other property c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, system.text.json

I know there are many similar questions on SO, however all the ones I've found require a shared base class in order to work.

With a stream of JSON data like this:

```
[
  {
    "webhookType": "order",
    "data": {
      "id": "eeiefj393",
      "orderProperty": "Value"
    }
  },
  {
    "webhookType": "customer",
    "data": {
      "id": 29238,
      "customerProperty": "Value"
    }
  }
]
```

I wish to deserialize this into two containers, `List<Customer>` and `List<Order>`. Where the two classes are as follows:

```
class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderProperty { get; set; }
    [...]
}

class Customer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerProperty { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

There may be shared property names however there are no shared properties + type between these two classes and so the solutions involing a sub class aren't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `JsonConverter`.

DataConverter

```
public class WebHookConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);

            if (item["webhookType"].Value<string>() == "order")
            {
                var webhook = new WebHook
                {
                    Type = item["webhookType"].Value<string>(),
                    Data = item["data"].ToObject<Order>()
                };

                return webhook;
            }
            else if (item["webhookType"].Value<string>() == "customer")
            {
                var webhook = new WebHook
                {
                    Type = item["webhookType"].Value<string>(),
                    Data = item["data"].ToObject<Customer>()
                };

                return webhook;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Objects

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(WebHookConverter))]
public class WebHook
{
    [JsonProperty("webhookType")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("orderProperty")]
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("customerProperty")]
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

Serialization

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WebHook>>(json);

var orderList = obj.Where(o => o.Type == "order").Select(o => o.Data).ToList();
var customerList = obj.Where(o => o.Type == "customer").Select(o => o.Data).ToList();
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Ah that's great. I just couldn't find an example of a JsonConverter which didn't use Base classes.